# How to solve jumping mouse cursor event?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, cursor

I have Windows 7 32 bit installed recently in my HP Pavillion laptop. Before this version, I used another Windows 7 32bit version. During that time, there was no problem with my mouse cursor. but this time, after installing this version, the problem started. The cursor automatically moves around the desktop even if the external mouse is stagnant. Again, in case of touchpad, when I am going to select anything, the cursor runs away!! I have tried uninstalling/reinsatlling the driver and there is no driver update in HP's website.